# How to Convert UK Income Levels to USA Income Levels

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, income, salary

I'm graduating with a PhD soon in the UK and now I'm trying to figure out how much I am worth in the workforce & see higher wages in the USA. I don't know if the numbers are adjusted for things like cost of living and I think that's something that would vary on the state you are in.

With all that in mind, I want to ask - How do I convert a UK salary to a USA one?

Comment: While I don't have a specific answer, some of the factors you'll need to consider are the state where the job is located, as taxes vary widely,(sometimes down to municipality), and healthcare costs, as it will be radically different from what you are used to even if you get employer sponsored insurance. A higher salary may also include longer expectations of work hours (with far fewer employee protection laws), and probably a lower amount of paid vacation.

Comment: I don't think that a direct conversion is the way to go. Markets vary, and at least in my field salaries in the US are significantly higher than in the UK (I've checked with my colleagues working in the same company, London office).

Comment: As @windwally already mentioned, there is no distinct formular to apply over all states. Your income depends heavily on your profession, industry, even the emlpoyer/company etc. Also keep in mind that accomodation in i.E. [Smackover (Arkansas)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Smackover,+Arkansas+71762,+USA/@33.3637811,-92.7504485,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x863214f8ae5e1383:0x1137982eb24e0cac!8m2!3d33.3648506!4d-92.7250061) will cost you far less than in i.E. Silicon Valley..

Comment: The type of PhD will make a very large difference; Engineering and science will give you enough income to live almost anywhere. Long ago during the UK "brain drain" ( about 1970), our lab hired more than 20 UK engineers and scientists. I knew many well ; the only regrets they spoke of was separation from family. That is, they were very happy with the standard of living ( Chicago suburbs) .

Comment: @iLuvLogix - "cost you far less than in **i.E.** Silicon Valley" - I think you mean "**e.g.** Silicon Valley".

Comment: A lot depends on where in the US and where in the UK you are comparing.

Comment: @littleadv I'd be surprised if there was *any* field for which UK salaries were better than equivalent US salaries, though of course its not easy to make the move visa-wise if you're not highly skilled.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As a European who's currently living in North America, I feel that there's a lot of confusion over salary comparisons between different markets. Let’s break it down step by step:

#### Currency

First of all, **think in one currency**, even if the two currencies are close in value. 1 GBP is currently 1.2 US dollars. Or conversely 1 US dollar is 0.83 GBP. Convert all the numbers you see into one currency to get an objective measure of your expected personal income. Forgetting about currency conversion is especially prevalent for countries whose currencies are "dollars" - a Canadian dollar is worth merely 0.73 US dollars, regardless of what it’s called, but Canadians often make the mistake of comparing the two as if they have the same value.

#### Location

Remember that the US is a huge country, so there are more cities to choose from than just New York or San Francisco. Just like there are cities other than London in the UK. It becomes especially important when you add taxation into the mix, as different US states have [different tax levels](https://www.thebalance.com/state-income-tax-rates-3193320). Working for a company in North Dakota won't yield you the same salaries as working for a company in California, so don't base your calculations about the entire country based on just one location.

#### Benefits

If you're employed as an office employee at a major company, you have access to most of the benefits provided "free of charge" by the government in UK. Healthcare is always covered and is usually more accessible in the US than the "free" healthcare in the UK. For example, a person with a good health plan can usually get an appointment with any specialist within a couple of weeks, compared to waiting for several months at British clinics. It gets more difficult if you contract a long-term disease such as cancer, but as a European this is of very little concern as you can always pack up and move back to your home country.

Vacation days are a little worse than what you get in Europe. The average highly-paid office employee would have around 21 vacation days per year, compared to an average of 28 days in Europe. There are also a bit more public holidays in the UK. So you should deduct one week's worth of wages from your US salary to get the vacation-adjusted version.

Retirement benefits are theoretically better in the UK, but in practice you're [extremely likely to get screwed](https://fantasticanachronism.com/2021/06/14/on-the-pension-apocalypse/) by the time you retire as birth rates remain too low to support Europe's current pension system. In comparison, the US offers you numerous retirement saving options that are more reliable than your home country's pension fund, as long as you save up a healthy amount each year.

#### Moving with a family

If you have children, there are a couple of additional variables to add into the mix. In the UK, you can get free kindergarten starting from the age of 3. In the US free childcare only starts from the age of 5 in the form of pre-school. Elementary and high school are free in both countries and comparable in quality. University education in the US is more expensive than in the UK, though by how much will vary depending on the college and the scholarships you're eligible for. If you relocate to the US, your child won't be eligible for [home fee status](https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/eligibility-for-home-fee-status-and-student-support-in-england/) back in England unless they spend at least 3 years in the UK first - though even with "overseas status" tuition might still be cheaper.

#### Salary after tax

It’s very important to **completely forget** about gross salaries and focus on net (after tax) salaries. This makes a big difference as the total tax rate can [range from 10% to 50%](https://files.taxfoundation.org/legacy/docs/OECD_Tax_Wedge_Charts-04.png), depending on the country.

Let's compare net salaries at the same company in two cities across the ocean: London and [Seattle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seattle). Seattle is not as big of a city as London but still has expensive real estate costs as seen below.

- Google Seattle [pays out](https://www.glassdoor.ca/Salary/Google-Software-Engineer-Seattle-Salaries-EJI_IE9079.0,6_KO7,24_IL.25,32_IM781.htm) an average of $148k in base salary and $68k in stocks per year, for a total compensation of $216k per year. This [comes out](https://smartasset.com/taxes/washington-tax-calculator) to **$158k per year** after tax.
- Google London [pays out](https://www.glassdoor.com/Salary/Google-Software-Engineer-London-Salaries-EJI_IE9079.0,6_KO7,24_IL.25,31_IM1035.htm) a base salary of GBP 74k and 13k in stock bonuses, for a total compensation of GBP 87k, for a [net pay](https://www.gov.uk/estimate-income-tax) of GBP 56k or **$68k per year** after tax.

Now let’s deduct your real estate costs, as they form the biggest difference in living costs. Prices on food, electronics, dining, etc., are usually a small part of your budget and are comparable across all Western countries. You can also ignore differences in transportation costs if you compare real estate prices in the downtown area, as this way you can just walk to work in both countries.

- A 3 bedroom apartment in downtown Seattle [costs around $3.9k per month](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/Seattle) or $47k per year, leaving you **$111k per year** after real estate costs.
- A 3 bedroom place in downtown London [will also set you back $3.9k per month](https://www.numbeo.com/cost-of-living/in/London) or $47k per year, leaving you **$21k per year**. If you instead rent outside the city center, you'll have $37k/year left over.

This is just one example of a calculation, as not everyone will be moving from the UK to the US to work as a software engineer for Google. Compare the total compensation in the UK with total compensation in the US for the same job to figure out which location is more profitable in your specific case. You can also use Numbeo's figures for a 1-bedroom apartment instead of a 3-bedroom one - or just lookup a local real estate website. In general, the US should always win for [STEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Science%2C_technology%2C_engineering%2C_and_mathematics) occupations, especially if you're working for a gigantic multinational corporation like Google.

Once again note how important it is to compare two *very* specific locations rather than "UK" against "USA". Moving the comparison from Seattle to NYC will make you lose 12% on state income tax as well as pay higher prices for real estate. Sometimes it might make sense to choose a different US city to move to or just relocate from London to a cheaper UK city instead.

#### Conclusion

Use the above methodology to obtain the **precise** amount of money you will earn living in each location, taking into account your personal situation and living expenses. Using "rules of thumb" is unnecessary and can lead to incorrect assumptions. And as we all know, assumption is the mother of all screw ups. Spending a few days on building up a spreadsheet with all the nitty gritty details is a worthy time investment when it comes to making huge personal decisions.

Comment: Also see this post for an "EU to US" comparison: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/538/how-to-match-eu-income-to-us-salary/15439#15439

Comment: Your answer talks about comparing Seattle with Zürich and then goes on to use London everywhere. I guess you forgot to edit some bits of the answer? And by the way, cancer treatment is very often outrageously expensive, super urgent and it also takes lots of time. Sorting out a transatlantic move at the same time doesn't sound like a viable option at all.

Comment: @TooTea if it’s urgent you’ll be covered by your American employer sponsored insurance. If it takes years you’ll have time to move back. As a European you get to have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: I'm not sure if you included it in the 12% state income tax difference, but NYC also has a city tax. So looking at specific areas is a little bit more than just looking at state + federal vs the taxes faced in the UK due to local taxes and sales tax and differences in how the state treats various federally tax advantaged plans. @TooTea regarding Cancer, AFAIK every US based healthcare plan has a yearly max out of pocket. Save/budget 2 years worth of that yearly max out of pocket through an HSA and you can get treatment in the US for 2 years as you plan the move back home if necessary.

Comment: @DavidJacobsen I’d also note that wait times for treatment are shorter in the US so you want to be in America when initially diagnosed.

Comment: What you call kindergarten is called preschool in the US. US kindergarten is at age 5 and is included in free public education.

Comment: @Barmar what about ages 0.5-4.9? In the UK two of those years are free, in the US they are not.

Comment: @JonathanReez Right. Kindergarten is the first level that's free in the US. Before age 3 it's generally called day care -- they're just caring for the children while the parent works, not "teaching" anything.

Comment: Under *Location*, it's not just the tax rates that are different. Wages themselves are very different in different locations, NYC/LA/Seattle vs. Omaha/St. Louis for example. The pay in an expensive city might be 2x-3x that of an inexpensive city for the same job title.

Comment: @Barmar answer edited

Comment: @TooTea Zurich mention removed

Comment: @shoover fixed!

Comment: It's wrong to claim an expat or their children can simply return at will to the UK for access to free or highly subsidised healthcare/university. One cost of emigrating for an extended period of time is losing some of these rights - they are residence-based, not just citizenship-based. For example, under current rules, you would need to send your child home *three years before starting university* to be eligible for "home" fees: otherwise they must pay the (massively higher) "overseas" fees. https://commonslibrary.parliament.uk/eligibility-for-home-fee-status-and-student-support-in-england/

Comment: Free NHS care is also residence based, see e.g. https://www.nhs.uk/using-the-nhs/healthcare-abroad/moving-abroad/planning-your-healthcare ... For someone considering emigrating only temporarily rather than permanently, or moving back and forth, it may also be worth considering how having commitments or savings on both sides of the Atlantic interacts with the pension and tax-free savings schemes of both countries. The pessimistic treatment of UK pensions in this answer seems to ignore private pension schemes (or alternatives like the use of ISAs in retirement planning) which complicates things

Comment: @Silverfish thanks, higher education bit fixed. Re: NHS, you can be [eligible from day one if you move back](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/using-the-nhs-when-you-return-to-live-in-the-uk), assuming I read the rules correctly - so if you get cancer, you can just pack your bags and move back whenever your US insurance stops covering you (which can happen for very long cancer treatments).

Comment: @Silverfish re: pensions, the US equivalent (Social Security) is unlikely to be of much use if you're under the age of ~40 as the worker-to-retiree ratio just keeps on increasing. Same goes for the UK government pension scheme - its basically a Ponzi scheme reliant on high birth rates. However 401k (private savings scheme) is government independent and should be much more reliable. Does the UK offer an equivalent scheme where you can put in pre-tax money and then withdraw them tax-free after a certain age?

Comment: The discussion of health insurance costs in the US is a bit oversimplified.  First, some employers require the employee to pay a significant part of the insurance premium, which can be many thousands of dollars per year.  Second,health insurance plans typically have an annual deductible that must be paid by the employee before benefits start.  Finally, there are co-insurance and co-pay requirements that may be significant.  You should consider the cost of premiums and the plan”Out of Pocket Maximum”

Comment: @BrianBorchers My own premiums plus out of pocket maximum is less than $2k/year. If someone is willing to sponsor your H1B or L1 work visa it’s unlikely your plan will be much worse than that. It’s actually the other way around - Europeans over complicate how the US healthcare system works because they keep reading stories from locals with no insurance or very poor insurance plans.

Comment: @jonathanreez try $6K per year in premiums and $7.5 K out of pocket max at a public university where the majority of faculty are on visas.

Comment: @BrianBorchers oh, yeah, academia is pretty bad. But most people move to work for corporations.

Comment: I'd be careful with "Ponzi" claims. Birth rates aren't the only factor to keep pension schemes sustainable: there's net migration, tighter eligibility rules (eg raising pension age), letting real-terms value of the pension shrink via inflation (likely supplemented with means-tested top-ups for the very poorest), raising the tax burden or in the extreme case even money-printing. It's hard to know what real-terms state pension provision will be in 30-50 years' time-much depends on state of economy & relative political power of young vs old-but Ponzi-style "no money left" collapse seems unlikely

Comment: Think the way you wrote up NHS eligibility is fair, but the need to switch residence back to UK is potentially highly disruptive. My point is it's somewhat misleading to suggest a Brit in America gets the "best of both worlds" due to continued eligibility for UK state provision, as a certain degree of sacrifice may be needed to regain access to it. Re pensions: UK citizens also save for retirement both via private pension schemes (income put into scheme is untaxed; tax is paid when draw retirement income out) & tax-free savings/investment accounts (i.e. taxed income in, untaxed income out)

Comment: Anyone moving mid-career, or who works in multiple countries before retiring, or intending to retire back in UK or a 3rd country, faces complex tax/pension planning challenges. Having built up private pension pots or tax-free savings in one country, can you still pay in or get tax relief if working elsewhere? Will any UK state pension you're eligible for be frozen on retirement there (eg Canada) or will you get annual increases (eg USA)? https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/state-pensions-annual-increases-if-you-live-abroad/countries-where-we-pay-an-annual-increase-in-the-state-pension

Comment: @Silverfish Re: pensions. You're right that the government would never literally "run out of money" (that's all but impossible) - but at the same time you'll find it hard to retire at the age of 65 if you just rely on the government. The US 401k program allows you to withdraw money starting from the age of 55 and since its just your own personal savings, its unlikely this threshold would be increased.

Comment: @Silverfish Re: NHS I'm not sure what is "highly disruptive"? If you've got cancer and need to spend years in treatment, there will be plenty of time to sell your real estate, buy something else in the UK and then move back home, all while still covered by your original US plan. The problem for Americans is that they might be screwed with no backup plan, but as a Brit you just move back home and that's it.

Comment: @Silverfish Re: pensions while moving. Its really not too complicated. In the case of 401k, you can't contribute if you move away, but you also don't lose the money/privileges. You'll withdraw it at the age of 55/60, just like any American. And I'd be very cautious about not falling into the trap of "oh its so complicated I'm not even going to bother!". A highly qualified professional might stand to gain something like an extra 5 million pounds over the duration of their career by jumping across the pond - that's too much money to give up because of some tax difficulties!

Comment: Not everyone gets years of notice before big medical bills start! Clearly a UK citizen taking the option of moving back across the Atlantic for treatment is using an advantage US citizens lack, but doing so is still disruptive & potentially costly (forced property sales often are; plus loss of job, support network etc) & they wouldn't face this burden if they'd stayed in UK. Migration to US can mean bearing a small but real risk of large, unanticipated medical bills; entitlement to free NHS care if you move back only partly mitigates this risk. In several respects, US life is "higher variance"

Comment: @Silverfish you absolutely do, if you're an employee of a company big enough to sponsor your immigration. Those kind of employers would have: a) a pretty good plan with a clear out-of-pocket maximum for both in-network and out-of-network doctors. In my own case that's $2k/year b) Some sort of a disability policy letting you get treatment for ~3 months without losing employment/insurance c) Option to purchase a reasonably priced [COBRA plan](https://www.shrm.org/resourcesandtools/tools-and-samples/hr-qa/pages/howlongdoescobralast.aspx) for up to 18 months of coverage.

Comment: @Silverfish so you'll get at least 21 months of advanced notice, assuming your injuries are so bad you're no longer able to work. Most employers also have a disability insurance plan for situations like that, covering a large chunk of your salary for 6-12 months after you're no longer able to work. So there's not much of a variance, really. Worst case scenario: you get into car accident, can never work again, spend 21 months on medical leave + COBRA, collect disability insurance, spend these months slowly packing and moving back. Have your cake and eat it too, just like I said.

Comment: I did intend to acknowledge the above but ran out of space in the comment! Long-term, life in US is apparently higher-variance than in UK (looking at eg medical bankruptcy stats). Someone who migrates for the long haul can't guarantee they'll keep their original job forever, or even if they'll eventually need to make a career change. If you enter the US as a high-skill professional (not the only route to entry but most likely for this Q) you'll likely do well, financially better than if you stay in UK, but seems fair to say US system generally gives weaker support for life's bumps in the road

Comment: I don't think it's fair to keep comparing US 401k to UK state pension, as UK professionals can get majority of their retirement income from private pension/investment schemes. If you're a "social security is Ponzi" doomster, it's also unwise to treat private pension wealth as totally safe just because it's your "own money": a future tax raid on private pension wealth is an oft-touted progressive solution to any demographic/economic squeeze on government ability to finance provision for the elderly (a risk UK savers/investors are warned of in the small print!) so there are correlated risks here

Comment: @Silverfish You are totally correct - a US citizen is a lot less protected from tail risks than a UK citizen. But herein lies the beauty of moving to America with a UK passport - best of both worlds! If anything happens, you GTFO and go back to your old British life.

Comment: @Silverfish agreed - but there's a catch! In the US you'll have a lot more money to save up in the first place compared to your British counterpart - I gave the example of Google in my post. You can put down $20k/year into 401k alone, which is a sum even a Google engineer in London would somewhat struggle to put into a private pension plan. So, yes, a British employee can still have a private pension plan, but they could put down a lot less into it. As for government clawback - this is even possible for bank accounts (as seen with Cyprus), but insanely unlikely.

Comment: Those differences in average salary numbers are very significant. They seemed to be based on GlassDoor, is there any way to be confident the represent similar roles/experience?

Comment: @Jontia I personally know 20+ Google engineers and can attest to this fact. If you don’t trust my judgement you could always go on TeamBlind.com and start a new question thread for Google employees.

Comment: Currently Glassdoor has ~2,000 Google Seattle listings, but only 123 list stock compensation, which averaged at the ~68k used in this answer. If you insert the ~1880 people who received zero in stock compensation, that's going to bring your Seattle total compensation down closer to 160k before taxes. So the final comparison would be 73k to 21k, which still favors Seattle but not by quite so much.

Comment: (continued) Overall, I liked the methodology and the links to useful calcs (+1)

Comment: @codeMonkey sure, you're free to double check the numbers. When it comes to huge personal decisions like this it wouldn't be unreasonable to spend a full month crunching the numbers and making sure you're not making any false assumptions. Most important aspect is to **never** use rules of thumb and always calculate everything to the penny, as your entire life trajectory depends on it. I can suggest perusing TeamBlind, Levels.FYI and HackerNews for additional data on compensation.

Answer (score 19):

Having once had to do this while moving from the UK to Canada, I can say that there isn't a straightforward conversion rate. Things you need to take into account:

- **Currency exchange rate**
- **Cost of living.** Try to get a general idea of how much everyday things cost. Something like "purchasing parity power" will give you a good indication.
- **Cost of accommodation** This usually isn't factored into cost of living, and varies widely across the US.
- **Taxes.** Don't forget that the US has at least two levels of income tax, federal and state. Also check sales tax levels (VAT) and social security/NI contribution levels.
- **Conditions of employment** In the US you are going to get longer working hours and shorter vacations, as well as less job security. Your compensation should reflect this.
- **Healthcare.** In the UK your healthcare is taken care of. In the US somebody has to pay for it. Make sure your employer has a good healthcare plan or you may be paying for it yourself (or facing an unexpected medical bill).
- **Any pension or other benefits.**

Comment: Just to add, while in general the exchange rate can be a useful indicator, *technically* it's irrelevant to this comparison unless OP plans to work in one country, and then move to the other - the conversion between dollars and pounds is only relevant if you get pounds and need dollars, or vise versa. If you live in london, your need for dollars is very limited (i.e. zero)

Comment: If you have a presence in two countries then your need for the other currency is not zero. You may be planning on retiring back in your home country, and your eventual pensions needs may be in pounds. You may have debts in your country of origin.

Comment: Note also that "cost of living" depends on your lifestyle. The more you adapt to the lifestyle of the country you are living in, the lower your costs will be. Living an expatriate lifestyle, where you try to do the same things you would do at home, always costs a lot more.

Comment: @DJClayworth I think that falls in to my "unless" statement

Comment: @BeB00 conversion rates are important because people make the fallacy of comparing two currencies as if they're a 1:1 equivalent when the values are "close enough". 1 GBP is 1.2 USD, so if OP forgets to convert they'd be 20% wrong in their calculations.

Comment: @JonathanReez barring the cases I mentioned, the exchange rate is not relevant. If a burger is $5 in new york and £5 in london, the conversion rate for burgers is 1:1. Prices are what matter, not exchange rates that are driven by a large number of macroeconomic trends. A few months ago, the rate was 1.3 - have prices in the UK decreased 10% in that time? No (unless you're buying in dollars). As I said, the exchange rate can be interesting depending on your circumstance, but by itself it is not relevant (although you can think about what it indicates).

Comment: @BeB00 you still need the exchange rate to get a final apple-for-apples comparison of "savings after taxes, real estate and other unavoidable costs", aka "disposable income". If I have 50k USD left per year in the US vs 40k GBP in the US, I need the exchange rate to understand where I'm better off.

Comment: @JonathanReez Again, thats not the case. If you're not spending pounds, it doesn't matter how many pounds your dollars are worth. Can it be relevant? Yes, maybe, if youre spending pounds - if youre importing stuff (probably not burgers) from the UK or travelling to the UK - in every other situation, the rate is not relevant. It is not "apples to apples" if your 50k usd is worth 30K GBP or 40K GBP unless you can spend the GBP. Purchasing Power Parity is a much more relevant metric.

Comment: @BeB00 my logic makes more sense with a currency like JPY: if I tell you your salary after tax in Tokyo will be 13m yen vs. 90k GBP in London, how do you assess which option is better without using the conversion rate?

Comment: @JonathanReez you look at the relative costs of things in the local currency - one metric being the Purchasing Power Parity. The current PPP is ¥100.4 per $1, but the exchange rate is ¥135 per $1 - clearly the latter is less relevant if you're living and working in japan

Comment: @BeB00 that's a fair adjustment, but you're still using an exchange rate - you just adjust it for PPP as well

Comment: @JonathanReez that is incorrect. The "exchange rate" is the rate at which you can exchange currency. The PPP is completely unrelated, and is just what I said - comparing the local prices of comparable things - the price of a 1 bedroom flat in yen japan vs the price of a 1 bedroom flat in USD in the USA, the cost of a burger, etc.

Comment: @BeB00 PPP = exchange rate against USD * cost-of-living adjustment. So you can't get around the fact that exchange rate is a factor.

Comment: @JonathanReez that is factually incorrect. The exchange rate of USD does not come into the calculation of PPP, which is detailed here (https://www.oecd.org/sdd/prices-ppp/purchasingpowerparities-frequentlyaskedquestionsfaqs.htm). You can take the PPP and divide it by the exchange rate if you want, but the number that you get is only relevant if you already care about the exchange rate, which is what you're trying to argue, so that logic is circular.

Comment: @BeB00 it literally talks about using an exchange rate in the very first paragraph: *If it costs 2.3 euros in France and 2.00$ in the United States then the PPP for Coca-Cola between France and the USA is 2.3/2.00, or 1.15. This means that for every dollar spent on a litre of Coca-Cola in the USA, 1.15 euros would have to be spent in France to obtain the same quantity and quality - or, in other words, the same volume - of Coca-Cola.*

Comment: @JonathanReez that is not "the exchange rate" which you're talking about, its just "a ratio", i.e. literally the PPP. The exchange rate you've been talking about this whole time is the actual currency exchange rate. This PPP ratio is literally the thing that I'm saying is useful, in contrast to "the exchange rate" which you're saying is useful.

Comment: @BeB00 PPP is a good metric for analyzing the economy as a whole but sucks when it comes to individual decisions where you can calculate *exact* costs for nearly everything you might have to buy - and yes, that's what you should be doing when making a choice impacting the next decade of your life. See my answer for how it should be done. Rules of thumb and approximations belong in econ papers, not individual decisions. So exchange rates are absolutely crucial.

Comment: @JonathanReez our whole discussion that we just had shows that you are incorrect, doesn't it? There are two parts - actual living costs for your situation, and then rules of thumb for comparing currencies. I absolutely agree that the first part is the most important, and I think we have agreed on that for the entire conversation. The second part is where you're saying that the exchange rate is important, and nothing you've said seems to support that. If you want a rule of thumb for comparing currencies, the PPP is a good metric, which you also seem to agree on?

Comment: @BeB00 PPP is a good first order approximation. You then need to lookup specific prices and use the exchange rate to figure out which location is more profitable to work at. I would never use it to make the final decision on whether or not I'm moving somewhere, as its just too generic, not to mention how its a value for the country as a whole rather than for specific cities/states. So instead you convert all the prices/salaries into one currency (USD, EUR, GBP, whatever) and then work with that in all your calculations.

Comment: @JonathanReez I thought we had already covered this. The initial step of converting all the salaries to dollars is unnecessary, because you then have to convert all of the local prices to dollars too, using the same rate. You could do that if you wanted, but it doesnt change any comparison since you're just multiplying everything by the same arbitrary number (the fx exchange rate). Since that number (used this way) is fairly arbitrary, you might as well use the PPP, or you could use any other random number (like 1).

Comment: @BeB00 and like I said, (PPP = exchange rate * generic living costs adjustment). Since we're calculating exact living costs, we just use the exchange rate and don't need the living costs adjustment as we can easily get the latest prices from both countries. Can the exchange rate change in the future? Yes, it can, and this happens all the time. But since we don't know whether it will go up or down, we just use the latest exchange rate that we have. If you want, you could also use the 5-year average for example.

Comment: @JonathanReez the whole point of using the PPP is that it allows you to *not* have to get the prices for every little thing, and instead allows you to approximate some things. As you said in your answer, you would subtract all the big things (rent, car, insurance, medical etc) and then be left with a number for other spending. The PPP allows you to see the equivalent of those leftover numbers in different currencies, because the local prices of everything is *already baked in*. Again, who cares if the FX rate is $1.2:£1 if a £1 ice cream is $1 in the usa

Comment: @JonathanReez the cost of living adjustment is the whole point, and thats what the PPP is. COLA is what you care about. In order to get the COLA using the exchange rate, you would have to do GBP/FXRate * PPP/FXrate. This is completely unnecessary because you're dividing both by the same number. You can just do GBP*PPP.

Comment: @BeB00 so you agree that PPP is calculated using the exchange rate multiplied by COLA, right? You could use PPP to adjust the cost of ice cream but in practice no one cares about the cost of something that's such a tiny percent of their budget. Your only concern is in regards to *inelastic* expenses: rent/mortgage, transportation, medicine, core services. The hourly price of hiring a plumber is more important for how rich you feel - and that's something you have to lookup for any individual city.

Comment: @JonathanReez NO! the PPP is calculated completely separately! No step of the PPP process involves the FX exchange rate. I agree with you that if you wanted to, you could adjust everything to FX dollars by dividing everything by the FX rate, or you could adjust everything to any other sort of basis by dividing by any other random number. My literal entire point is that the FX rate is irrelevant.

Comment: @JonathanReez the cost of groceries absolutely is important to people budget, as are the costs of the many other things that the PPP includes, like clothes, internet access, and a whole load of other stuff. You also mentioned "disposable income" in your second comment as being the point of using the FX rate, and this entire conversation has been about how the FX rate is irrelevant for disposable income, and how PPP is relevant.

Comment: @BeB00 the PPP is basically a lagging indicator, so if you want you can use the 3-year average exchange rate instead of the latest one for a similar effect. And yes, it directionally matters for disposable income, but since any individual person knows their own basket of goods, they're better off making their own comparison instead of relying on baskets made up by a team of economists. I.e. you can avoid getting a car in the UK but would absolutely need it living in Los Angeles - how is PPP useful for you in this case?

Comment: @JonathanReez PPP is very useful because its a whole basket of goods. The price of bread might be one thing, the price of gas another, and the price of shoes yet another, but on alltogether it should be pretty relevant. It seems like you agree that the PPP is useful, but now youre saying that you could use a 3 year FX average, and I still have no idea why? The PPP is literally exactly what you want, so why would you then try to approximate it some other worse way when the number is already available? The 3 year USD GBP is 0.76, the PPP is 0.69. They're different so why use the irrelevant one?!

Comment: @JonathanReez I feel like this conversation is going in circles, so it's probably not productive to continue. I've said my part, and you can say your part, and then it will be available for anyone interested to read.

Comment: @BeB00 because PPP is a generic attempt to measure the price of a sample basket of goods. That basket of goods is *not* what *you personally* are going to consume. Maybe you'll live in NYC and won't drive. Maybe you'll be in DC and would drive a tiny Corolla. Maybe you'll be in Texas and buy an electric F-150. Whatever you want to do, there's a price tag attached and you can use that price tag to figure out where you're better off living. Find a basket *you* care about and use the exchange rate to convert between the two basket values.

Answer (score 8):

There's not a straight conversion. I don't know how widely salaries vary in the UK, bunt in the US, they can be very different depending on not only the local cost of living, but how the market is for those jobs. Even cost of living is somewhat of a guess, since different people have different lifestyles that may or may not align with the "average" cost of living.

You could get a bit of a baseline by just looking at currency exchange rates, and maybe a little closer by looking at cost-of-living indexes, but you might find that jobs in different areas pay more or less than what currency rates and cost of living alone would show. It all matters where you want to live, when the demand is in that area for your job, and how well you can negotiate your salary.

Comment: I'd note that its a very much straight conversion if given a particular occupation / level of skill. All the data is available online and is more or less easy to look up. You might spend a few hours doing the research and putting it into a spreadsheet, but that's nothing when it comes to figuring out your future. For many highly skilled Europeans moving across the pond will net them millions of extra euros in lifetime income after tax.

Answer (score 0):

**Be prepared to fund you own retirement in the US**

I've seen this mentioned in other replies, but I think it deserves more emphasis. Many employers in the US will not offer a pension, and you will be expected to fund your own retirement. This will mainly be done through tax-advantaged vehicles such as a 401(k) which your employer *may* contribute to (generally by matching part of your own contributions).

As a rule of thumb, you should save 15% of your pre-tax salary for retirement.
  https://www.fidelity.com/viewpoints/retirement/how-much-money-should-I-save

You should probably adjust US salaries by an similar amount to account for the pension you would be contributing to in the UK (though maybe less than 15%, assuming you might need to fund a complimentary pension).

Comment: That's true but keep in mind that the UK will likely be forced to raise the retirement age to ~70 by the time OP retires. The birth rates are just too low to sustain the current pension models.